# Add folder of images to Android app visible by intent

Tags: android, android-image

I want to add a folder of free images to my app, so that the user easily finds it with

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
    "Select image"), SELECT_IMAGE);
```

(Next step would be do let user click something to download another folder, perhaps at a cost.)

I only find ways to add images to the app so that direct links to the images can be shown in the app, but I didn't figure out how to let those image be part of the selection shown with the code above.

Comment: Didn't quite get the problem . But if you that your image should be listed in chooser then you must save all your image inside a directory in storage and send scan update to `MediaStore` . Then this directory will be accessible with `Intent`.

Comment: I think you understood correctly but just to be extra clear: I want to include sets of images inside my app, say 20-50 images in each set. I want the user of the app to be able to choose images among the sets for display/use on the app screen. (And, at a later date, add new sets, via download.)

Comment: If you want to let user chose from your set of images only then you have to create a custom gallery. Where all of your images will be listed . Look for custom gallery tutorials its easy to build .

Comment: Not only - I want the user to be able to user his/her own images, as well as from the built-in sets. Can I make the chooser shows folders "Downloads" "Camera" and "Built-in-set-1" and "Built-in-set-2" etc?

Comment: By default your image directory will show in system gallery with all other images . So whats the issue ?

Comment: That's great. The issue is just to find the best way to do it. `AssetManager`? Is it possible to automatically delete the created folders and images when the app is uninstalled?

Comment: For this You need to save the image in apps cache directory . Search for it . Not the AssetManger .